# Expo-notification - push notification does not show up on Android 11

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-notifications

Using Nokia 7.2 (Android 11) I can't make push notification to show up for my app.

Preconditions:

- On iOS everything works (local/push notification)
- Android local notification works (both foreground/background)
- I am using an eas standalone development build (apk)
- In my android device settings, all notifications are enabled
- ExpoToken is set properly, no error
- Push ticket and receipt are sent without an error (see below)
- FCM server key is set properly
- push notifications from other apps are working properly for this device

Unfortunately I have no other android device to test push notification, is it possible to test on emulator? If yes, then it doesnt work there either, because i tried already. No errors.

Client side code:

```
useEffect(() => {
      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) =>
        setExpoPushToken(token)
      );

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(setNotification(noti));

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        setNotification(response.notification);
      });

    return () => {
      notificationListener.current &&
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
          notificationListener.current
        );
      responseListener.current &&
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, [user]);

  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      await user_ref(user.uid).update({
        ["push_token"]: token,
      });
      setToken(token);
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    return token;
  }
```

It is basically the same as the documents says.

Then I send push notification manually to the right token:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" -d '{
  "to": "EXPOTOKEN",
  "title":"hello",
  "body": "world"
}'
```

Response is OK:

```
{"data":{"status":"ok","id":"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"}}%
```

Checking the receipt for the received id:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/getReceipts" -d '{
  "ids": [
    "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
  ]
}'
```

Response is OK:

```
{"data":{"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx":{"status":"ok"}}}%
```

Here is a screenshot of my app notification settings:
[image: app settings]

Without any errors, how and where to start troubleshooting?